# Request scoped singleton in NancyFx

Tags: c#, request, singleton, nancy

Is there a way in NancyFx to create a singleton that is only available within the request scope in which it has been created.

I am not thinking about a singleton created in the IOC container. I would like to create a singleton and have that be available from anywhere in the Nancy code without having to inject it.

I want to hide all access to the NancyContext behind my own implementation. The reason I do not want to use the Request IOC Container is that I then have to register everything that relies on the context explicitly in the request container. So I was hoping there was a way to hide the NancyContext object behind a singleton, that isn't shared between requests.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself here: "a singleton available **only** to the request within which it has been instantiated" and "available from **anywhere**". You may want to clarify your question with an example.

Comment: Hope that edit makes more sense... if not, then I will try to add more detail. Thanks for letting me know that it wasn't clear.

Comment: This is exactly what you should be using IoC for...

Comment: Ok, but everything that somehow depends on the request or anything that gets anything injected that depends on the request will then have to exist in the request container. I was hoping that I could wrap that nicely. I have a lot of controllers that would then have to be injected into every request, even though I only ever need one of them. What am I not understanding here? What do other people do? I feel like I have modelled things pretty bad here.